# What is the oldest known appearance of clairvoyance or telepathy in myth or folklore?

Tags: folklore

Clairvoyance is the sensing of an event, thought or fact by other means than the five physical senses; telepathy is the deliberate sending of a thought, feeling, knowledge or information using such means. What is the first known time that either is known to have appeared in mythology or folklore?

Comment: Those are not in themselves considered clairvoyance, but perception in dreams or while interpreting dreams can be clairvoyant.

Comment: In the ancient religion of Jainism, clairvoyance is regarded as "one of the five kinds of knowledge".